# Cannot find module 'winston'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, winston

I wrote a little module that uses winston to log stuff.

I used `sudo npm install -g winston` (it is on a vm...so i'm not too concerned with sudo, etc.

Log from npm:

```
winston@0.7.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/winston
├── cycle@1.0.2
├── stack-trace@0.0.7
├── eyes@0.1.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.2.9
├── pkginfo@0.3.0
└── request@2.16.6 (forever-agent@0.2.0, aws-sign@0.2.0, tunnel-agent@0.2.0, oauth-sign@0.2.0, json-stringify-safe@3.0.0, cookie-jar@0.2.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, mime@1.2.11, qs@0.5.6, hawk@0.10.2, form-data@0.0.10)
```

When I try to run my module in node I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'winston'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:373:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/name/Code/neon/neon-js-spike/logger.js:2:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

System versions:
ubuntu
node -v = v0.11.7-pre
npm -v = 1.3.8

P.S. I tried this on my home laptop (another ubuntu vm) and worked.

Comment: You could always install winston locally, in the same directory as your program.

Comment: installing it locally worked, but I don't understand how come on my other vm installing globally worked.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13):

If the suggestion of setting the class path hasn't worked, it might likely be that you need to use an npm link. See: http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/04/06/npm-1-0-link/

For winston goto the root folder of your script and use the command:

```
npm link winston
```

Comment: On windows, but sure to Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, where `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` is the path where your node modules are globally installed.

Comment: Same here, this worked for other modules, but not in this case

Answer (score 0):

In general, missing modules should be solved by setting `NODE_PATH` as @fakewaffle says. Assuming they're installed of course.

But for `winston`, this didn't work for me. For some reason, I had to update file permissions:

```
chmod o+rx -R /pathto/node_modules/winston
```

I don't know why it permissions get set incorrectly. This solution is for Ubuntu, presumably it works for other linuxes but not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

npm WARN winston-daily-rotate-file@3.2.3 requires a peer of winston@^2 || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

and i **have removed node_modules folder**
and made **npm install** to dependency. **it worked**

**Note:** check before deleting the that you have package.json

"winston": "^2.4.1",
"winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

if you use

> yarn

-> do `yarn install` before `yarn run dev`.